# Youtube uses "default" as a name for an object property

Tags: javascript, json, youtube, youtube-api

I've been using the Youtube json api for making a new mash-up.
Somewhere in the [response](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/denbuzze/favorites?v=2&alt=jsonc) you can find the following:

```js
{
"player":
  {
  "default":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v\u003deH5Iysm417U"
  }
}
```

I've always learned not to use any words mentioned in the reserved words section of the [ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) as identifiers. So as far as I know it's not allowed to use the name "default" as a property name. Why is Youtube doing this?

```js
player.default
```

To be honest, the above code works fine in a browser. But I had to change it to the code beneath in order to have no compile errors when using the Google closure compiler.

```js
player["default"]
```

It just feels wrong.
The most important question here is, can I do anything about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `Identifier` is not the same as a `PropertyName`.

`PropertyName` need only *not*  consist of reserved words when declared without quotes. When declared with quotes, then all strings are valid, even `"  "`.

Here is the list of the valid productions:

```
 PropertyName :    
     Identifier    
     StringLiteral    
     NumericLiteral
```

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf, 11.1.15

You cannot change the response from Youtube, and allthough there is nothing wrong with `player.default`, you will simply need to use the [] accessor if you want to avoid this error in the closure compiler.

But really, this is a bug with the compiler, not the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler might be flagging this up due to cross-browser compatibility issues.

I hit the same thing recently with both `default` and `extends` when creating a template library which uses code instead of parsing text. The code worked just fine, but the Closure Compiler complained about those keywords when used as properties... then I tried it in IE:

```
>>> var o = {default: 'test'}
SyntaxError: Expected identifier, string or number
>>> var o = {'default': 'test'}
>>> o.default
SyntaxError: Expected identifier
```